# How to get the updated Schema on column visibility change in Datagrid. (Material UI)?

Tags: material-ui

While referring to Datagrid documentation of [events](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/events/#catalog-of-events), I found that `columnVisibilityChange` can be used to detect all kinds of column visibility changes. But when I included it in y DataGrid component, it seems not to get triggered when I show/hide the columns. Here's how I am trying to detect the trigger:

```
export default function DataGridDemo(props) {
  let { updateSelections } = props;
  updateSelections =
    updateSelections || (() => console.log('Update Selections Not Configured'));
  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
      className={classes.DataGridComponents}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={props.data || rows}
        columns={props.schema || columns}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
          Footer: GridFooter,
        }}
        className={classes.root}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        scrollbarSize={5}
        pageSize={props.pageSize || 10}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
        density={props.density || 'compact'}
        onSelectionModelChange={updateSelections}
        columnVisibilityChange={(params) => {
          console.log(`Column State Changed: ${params}`);
        }}
        selectionChange={() => console.log('selection change')}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the event listeners, you have to add an on and capitalize the event listener term. Changing my code from:

```
columnVisibilityChange={(params) => {
          console.log(`Column State Changed: ${params}`);
        }}
```

to

```
onColumnVisibilityChange={(params) => {
          console.log(`Column State Changed: ${params}`);
        }}
```

worked for me.